# Finding the GCD using Counter - Python

Tags: python, counter

I am attempting to calculate the GCD of two numbers using the Counter class. I have implemented my factorisations and used an intersection to get the minimum factorisatons, however I am unsure of exactly how I can progress from here. To be more specific -

gcd(120, 500) has me at the point of a counter containing 2:2, 5:1

How can I use these numbers in a way that represents 2^2 x 5^1?

```
x = Counter(factors(a))  
y = Counter(factors(b))

min = x & y

return min
```

My current input/output:

In[29]: gcd(120, 500)

Out[29]: Counter({2: 2, 5: 1})

I am fairly new to Python, so any explanations and advice on how to progress would be appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: Counter is a type of dictionary. Just iterate over the dictionary and calculate the product.

Comment: why are you using a Counter?

Comment: Its required - yes, this is part of a tutorial, but I'm quite stuck and unable to get in contact with my tutor :)

I'll look into dictionary types a little closer, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a fairly simple answer in the end -

```
x = Counter(factors(a))  
y = Counter(factors(b))

min = x & y

gcd = 1

for key, value in min.items():
    gcd = gcd * key ** value

return gcd
```

Thank you everyone for your help, I feel like I certainly understand how to deal with both counter an dict classes far better now.

Comment: ... which is just where I hoped my reply would lead you.

Please "accept" one of the answers -- such as your own -- so that this question closes properly.

Comment: I'm not allowed to accept my own just yet, but I will do so :)

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the items of "min".
Start a running product, prod = 1
For each item:
  the key is the multiplier; the value is the power
  multiple "prod" by "key", "power" times.

When you've gone through all the factors in "min", prod is your GCD.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the [**`items`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) from the Counter object:

```
>>> counter = Counter({2: 2, 5: 1})
>>> import operator
>>> reduce(operator.mul, (factor ** count for factor, count in counter.items())
20
```

[**`reduce`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) keeps applying a function to values in a sequence and the previous result, until it has used everything in the sequence.

So we apply the multiplication operator [**`mul`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.mul) to everything yielded by the generator `(factor ** count for factor, count in counter.items())`

Comment: I've managed to get the answer 9 through some trial and error, however the answer as I'm lead to believe should be 20 (2^2 = 4, 5^1 = 5, 5*4 = 20). This is where I'm struggling. I'll keep at it!

Comment: @Forever_Lona where is `5*4` coming from?

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood somewhere, but my lecture notes suggest that to find the GCD, the results of 2^2 and 5^1 must be multiplied.

Comment: @Forever_Lona, what are you finding the gcd of, I cannot make any sense of your output, the gcd of 120 and 500 is 20

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham - thats what I am trying to get to. The current output is purely me checking that I am on the right track to get to the final answer of 20. My issue is how to go from having those numbers in the counter, to actually producing 20 as the answer.

@Peter Wood - thank you! I just came across that option myself, and it looks like its working just fine

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve your problem and learn Python at the same time is to explore the classes interactively. In your case, you could try the following

```
>>> import collections
>>> counter = collections.Counter()
>>> counter[2] = 2
>>> counter[5] = 1
>>> print counter
Counter({2: 2, 5: 1})
>>> dir(counter)
['__add__', '__and__', '__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__',   '__delattr__',
 '__delitem__', '__dict__', '__doc__', q__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__len__', '__lt__', 
 '__missing__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__or__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', 
 '___', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__', 'clear', ', 'elements', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'has_key', 'items', 'iteritems', 
 'iterkeys', 'itervalues', 'keys', 'most_common', ', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'subtract', 
 'update', 'values', 'viewitems', 'viewkeys', 'viewvalues']
```

At this stage, you should explore what each method does

```
>>> counter.keys()
[2, 5]
>>> counter.values()
[2, 1]
>>> counter.items()
[(2, 2), (5, 1)]
```

Let us confirm `items()` is the right way

```
>>> help(counter.items)
Help on built-in function items:

items(...)
    D.items() -> list of D's (key, value) pairs, as 2-tuples
```

Then the solution is easy - we want to add the exponents of each pair

```
>>> [ factor ** count  for factor, count in counter.items()]
[4, 5]
>>> sum([ factor ** count  for factor, count in counter.items()])
9
```

Comment: You don't need to build the list just to sum